# Find and move huge records from one collection to another in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

The source collection has 10 million records, I need to fetch the records from the source collection in batch and insert those records in destination collection.
The question is - In python, How can I fetch the documents from the source collection in batch and insert those documents in the destination collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $out or $merge. Add additional aggregation pipeline stages to exclude documents present in the destination already.